# Rotating banner images are displayed one below the other

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When I try to implement rotating banner (RotatingImagesComponent)images are getting displayed one below the other in hybris 1905 on Any quick help is appreciated. I have tried SimpleResponsiveBannerComponent, but same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to add a slider/carousel to your storefront.

The `RotatingImagesComponent` is a container used to render multiple `BannerComponent` components in a carousel.

Try adding `BannerComponent` type of components inside the banners section of `RotatingImagesComponent`.

Comment: Yes, I have added 4 banner uids. But still all the images are coming vertical. Do I need to use UI to make it as slider.

Comment: in RotatingImagesComponent try changing the 'rotating effect' attribute, but I doubt that's the issue here, vikas's answer might make more sense

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar issue in past, in my case it was because of conflict between different versions of the bootstrap file(stand-alone file and CDN). If no problem with the hybris, please check the UI side.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your static files (js, CSS, etc) were not loaded properly.
Check first the console and network in the browser's developer tools for the particular page. to identify the errors that might be there